# Visual JQuery UI form designer

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, forms, widget

I'm looking for some gui-tool (or service) to visual design jquery-ui forms and widgets. (Like form builder in Delphi or Visual Studio).
Could you suggest any tool which allows to create web-form layout by mouse clicking and less code writing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am plan to build one and will be hosted in google code, would you interested to join the project? By the way, the project was kicked off, please see this blog post at http://limcheekin.blogspot.com/2011/01/kick-off-jquery-form-builder-plugin.html

Answer (score 5):

"Visual jQuery" - I know this is kind of an old post but I am working on a project that will allow a visual experience when building html, css and jQuery.

The project url is [codeCanvas.org](http://www.codeCanvas.org/) and will be community driven and free to use.

Hopefully it will help some folks as I really appreciate this community.

Our beta is just about ready but until then.. you can check out the daily builds of the current alpha.

Would love anyone's feedback.

Best,

Jason

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no same service yet (answered in 2010)

Comment: You can see that I answered this question in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a project with a tool through drop and drag to position jquery and html objects.

The URL is
http://www.sqltxt.cl/products/vui/designer/visualUI.php?

Eun is a prototype, but it behaved for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I programmed one myself, its called vbms-form-editor its hosted at code.google here is a link to the project page: http://code.google.com/p/vbms-form-editor/ it is easy to create new widgets and already supports the common html input types, it also supports jqueryui widgets like date. If you have suggestions on how it can be improved then just write me on google. If your interested you are welcome to join the project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a visual tool : http://wooby.altervista.org/

join to open source project to improve it and share with community